# Is there a way to get ROS_INFO, ROS_ERROR, etc to output line numbers?

Tags: ros, ros-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The title says it all. Is there a flag somewhere I can set to get the ROS_INFO/ROS_ERROR/... macros to output line numbers, or is that something I'm going to have to feed to ROS_INFO myself by using **LINE**?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46806/is-there-a-way-to-get-ros_info,-ros_error,-etc-to-output-line-numbers?/) by [SuperElectric](https://answers.ros.org/users/3461/superelectric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-10-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole) page's section about **Console Output Formatting** is what you are looking for.

Essentially

```
export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT='[${severity}] [${time}]@${line}: ${message}'
```

- ${line} for \__LINE__
  * ${function} for _*func*_
- ${file} for \__FILE__
  * ${node} for the node name, no pre-processor equivalent.

---

Originally posted by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) with karma: 105 on 2014-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you double-click a given roslog message in rxconsole, it will bring up a window with this information.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SuperElectric](https://answers.ros.org/users/3461/superelectric/) on 2012-11-26**:
Hmm; this isn't working for me. I'm sure I could get it working, but before I invest energy in that, I'd like to revisit the original question: is there any way to get ROS_INFO to print the line number (without need of external tools like rxconsole)?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-11-27**:
What's not working? When you double-click a  line in rxconsole, it shows "Location" which is a file and line number. This information is contained in all messages on the `rosout` topic. If you `rostopic echo rosout` you will see `file:` and `line:` message fields for each rosout message.